# Disable Multitouch for kiosk mode

Tags: gnome, multi-touch, kiosk

We control some public stands for information. These things come with a 4 finger touch screen. Problem is, when a user swipes with 4 fingers, the GNOME menu appears. The user now can do a lot of things.

We already try to disable all gestures using a GNOME extension. Try to switch to Wayland hoping to control the 4 fingers, but without any luck.

Also tried to blacklist the Multitouch hid. But when we tried it, the complete screen stops working. We need GNOME, because it's the only desktop we've tried so far that works with touch out of the box. The screen is portrait, with a separate touch layer from Sharp.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?